# Subquery returned more than 1 value. with where clause in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure in which I pass a comma-separated id, I use this in `where` clause with case statement with 'IN'.

I get this error :

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

My procedure is

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[proc_generatdetail]
    @TagIds varchar(1000)
    @IsMinStock bit,
    @Tags varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        IMd.ItemCode, I.ITEM_No 
    FROM
        Item I
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblItemSize ITS ON I.ITEMCode = ITS.ItemId 
                        AND I.BranchId = ITS.BranchId           
    WHERE  
        CASE 
           WHEN @Tags IS NOT null  
              THEN ITS.SizeId 
           ELSE 1 END IN 
                (case when @Tags is not null then (select id from CSVToTable(@TagIds)) else (1) end)

END
```

`CSVToTabes` returs table of ids, and I don't have to use if - else condition. 
So please give solution for this if anyone have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select IMd.ItemCode, I.ITEM_No
from Item I left join
     tblItemSize ITS
     on I.ITEMCode = ITS.ItemId and
        I.BranchId = ITS.BranchId          
where case when @Tags IS NOT null
           then ITS.SizeId else 1
      END in (case when @Tags is not null then (select id from CSVToTable(@TagIds)) else (1) end)
```

A `case` statement has to return the same thing for all its conditions.  And, it can't return a set.  Just rephrase the logic without the `case`:

```
select IMd.ItemCode, I.ITEM_No
from Item I left join
     tblItemSize ITS
     on I.ITEMCode = ITS.ItemId and
        I.BranchId = ITS.BranchId          
where (@Tags is null) or
      (ITS.SizeId in (select id from CSVToTable(@TagIds))
```

The logic is easier to understand as well.

There is one situation where you would want the `case`.  That is when the function would return an error if given a `NULL` argument.  You could then phrase it as:

```
where 1 = (case when @Tags is null then 1
                when ITS.SizeId in (select id from CSVToTable(@TagIds) then 1
                else 0
           end)
```